# How can I separately build and develop libgomp (openMP runtime)?

Tags: gcc, openmp, libgomp

I am trying to make changes to the openMP runtime library ([GOMP](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/gomp/)). As far as I know, the library comes with GCC compiler but my goal is to work on GOMP alone. So I wonder how I can build and develop GOMP separately from GCC. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building libgomp separately of GCC is not supported upstream.  It can be done (you'd need to figure out some "lengthy" configure command lines, and so on), so you're mostly on your own if attempting that.  But: why wouldn't you just build libgomp in its standard GCC build environment?

Comment: Indeed. Only the first build will be long, later rebuilds will only rebuild whatever you modified.

Comment: It is just slowing down my machine so I thought it would be better if I can find a way to build GOMP separately. Thank you guys for the help.